# jQuery ajax JSON to php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I hope you can help.
I have the following js code:

```
if ((width >= 360) && (width <= 2400) && (drop >= 360) && (drop <= 2400)){
            $.post("file.php",{
                change: change, 
                width: width, 
                drop: drop, 
                typeselect: typeselect, 
                colour: colour,
                variations: vari
            },function(data){
                var info = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
```

vari in firebug comes back as

```
[{"variation_id":"1110","attributes":{"attribute_colour":"chocolate","attribute_type":"tape-38mm"},"image_title":"wooden-chocolate-tape","image_alt":"","price_html":"<span class=\"price\"><span class=\"amount\">£36.00<\/span><\/span>","availability_html":"","sku":"","weight":" kg","dimensions":"","min_qty":1,"max_qty":0,"backorders_allowed":false,"is_in_stock":true,"is_downloadable":false}]
```

For some reason it isn't posting anything for variations. Firebug says the POST is:

```
change  drop
colour  
drop    360
typeselect  
width   360
```

I'm assuming the vari is in JSON format.

Any help would be great.
Thanks
Mark

Comment: That's because "vari" is undefined

Comment: Sorry Wilmer. Earlier in the code I have

var vari = $("form.variations_form").attr("data-product_variations");

console.log(vari) returns the JSON above

Comment: What triggers `var vari = $("form.variations_form").attr("data-product_variations");`? Because if it runs after the ajax request is sent it could explain the missing `variations`.

Comment: That seems to be happening after the post is sent. Do console log just before the post and see which appears first in the console.

Comment: changed it to 

if ((width >= 360) && (width <= 2400) && (drop >= 360) && (drop <= 2400)){
    var vari = $("form.variations_form").attr("data-product_variations");
    $.post("'.get_template_directory_uri().'/wooden-blinds.php",{
     change: change, 
     width: width, 
     drop: drop, 
     slat: slat,
     typeselect: typeselect, 
     colour: colour,
     variations: vari
    },function(data){

No difference I'm afriad